# Swift UIPickerView Trigger Segue with IBAction

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uipickerview, ibaction

I am new to Swift and could use some advice on how to trigger a segue using an IBAction on button click. I'm able to segue using the picker however I want the button to trigger the segue. I tried triggering the function inside the IBAction but that isn't working. Appreciate any advice. Thanks.

```
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

    switch (row) {

    case 0: self.performSegueWithIdentifier("Segue0", sender: self)
    break;
    case 1: self.performSegueWithIdentifier("Segue1", sender: self)
    break;
    case 2: self.performSegueWithIdentifier("Segue2", sender: self)
    break;
    case 3: self.performSegueWithIdentifier("Segue3", sender: self)
    break;
    case 4: self.performSegueWithIdentifier("Segue4", sender: self)
    break;
    default: break;

    }
```

Here's the standard button:

```
@IBAction func selectButton(sender: AnyObject) {


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you're looking for is how to determine which row is selected from within the button function, you can use [UIPickerView.selectedRowInComponent(_:):](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPickerView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIPickerView/selectedRowInComponent:)

```
@IBOutlet weak var picker: UIPickerView! // Reference to picker from storyboard. 
@IBAction func selectButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    // Get the selected row. You only have one component, so the parameter is 0.
    let row = picker.selectedRowInComponent(0)

    // Switch block here
}
```

If in fact your segues are actually named "Segue0", "Segue1", etc., then you can replace the switch block with:

```
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("Segue\(row)", sender: self)
```

However, if you're using more descriptive segue names (as I hope you are), then you could also store the segue identifiers in an array and just use `row` as an index to the array:

```
let segues = ["thisIsASegue", "thisIsAnotherSegue", "etc"]

// In the function:
self.performSegueWithIdentifier(segues[row], sender: self)
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. Yes, I am using more descriptive segue names in my production app. I'll look into UIPickerView.selectedRowInComponent.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get this working using the following. Would appreciate any comments or more elegant solutions. :)

Added a global variable to hold the picker row selected:

```
var rowSelected = 0
var pickerData: [String] = [String]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Connect data:
    self.locationPicker.delegate = self
    self.locationPicker.dataSource = self

pickerData = ["Location 1", "Location 2", "Location 3", "Location 4", "Location 5"]

// The number of columns of data
func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

// The number of rows of data
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return pickerData.count
}

// The data to return for the row and component (column) that's being passed in
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    return "\(pickerData[row])"

}
// Capture the picker view selection
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

    rowSelected = row


}
@IBAction func selectButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    switch (rowSelected) {

    case 0: self.performSegueWithIdentifier("Segue0", sender: self)
    break;
    case 1: self.performSegueWithIdentifier("Segue1", sender: self)
    break;
    case 2: self.performSegueWithIdentifier("Segue2", sender: self)
    break;
    case 3: self.performSegueWithIdentifier("Segue3", sender: self)
    break;
    case 4: self.performSegueWithIdentifier("Segue4", sender: self)
    break;
    default: break;




}
```